# Calculating histogram equalization after converting to HSB values

Tags: java, image-processing, histogram

I am trying to equalize a color image. I was told to convert it into HSB and then perform equalization on brightness channel before converting it back into RGB.

I have so far calculated the frequencies but I am having issues with the scale factor. As I understand, scale factors in the case of colors are usually 255/(height*width) of the image. Can anyone please help with what to do in the case of brightness? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct when you say that you have to **convert the RGB image to HSB (or [HSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV)) color space to equalize a color image**.

However, I don't understand what you mean by scale factor, so I will describe the algorithm:

1. Convert the input image to HSB color space.
2. Using the B (brightness) channel, compute the frequency of each pixel value. In fact, you are computing the gray level [histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_histogram) of the image. If your image has 256 different brightness values, you can store the histogram in a vector `H[0..255]` where `H[i]` gives you the frequency of the i-th brightness value. To compute `H[i]`, **count the number of pixels with value i and divide by the number of pixels in the image**. If you sum all the entries of `H[i]` you should get the value `1.0`.
3. Using your histogram `H[i]`, compute a new vector `CDF[i]` where:

   `CDF[0] = H[0] and CDF[i] = CDF[i - 1] + H[i].`

   In fact, the `CDF[i]` vector stores [cumulative distribution function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization#Implementation) of the brightness values over the input image.
4. The last step consists in updating the B channel of your image: `B'[x,y] = 255 * CDF[B[x,y]]` where `B[x,y]` is the B value of the pixel at position (x,y) and  `B'[x,y]` is the new B value of the pixel at position (x,y). Again, this assumes that your image has 256 different brightness values.